# Where can i define common variables used in all test cases for cypress -

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a form which i am filling and every single test case takes different values for firstname, lastname and email. So i am creating the env variable values within each test case as the value changes each time rather than just one value in cypress.json
is there a way i can move the const variables i declared below to a section within cypress, can i move it to the hooks section??

```js
  //Second Test Case with Broker Company
  it('demotestnifty1', {
    env: {
        firstname: 'Lambda',
        lastname: 'Jonas',
        email: 'ljrfnew@gemini.com',
        }
    }, function () {
    const firstname = Cypress.env('firstname')
    const email = Cypress.env('email')
    const lastname = Cypress.env('lastname')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define them at the `describe()` or `context()` level, if the data will be the same for all tests in those blocks. This is similar to what you've already done in your `it()` block.

```js
describe('some test', { env: { foo: 'bar' } }, () => {
  it('logs foos value', () => {
    cy.log(Cypress.env('foo'); // logs 'bar'.
  });
});
```

[You could also store them in your `cypress.json` or `cypress.env.json` files.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Setting)

```js
// cypress.json
{
  ...
  'env': {
    'foo': 'bar'
  }
  ...
}

// cypress.env.json
{
  'foo': 'bar'
}
```

Cypress will pick up variables included in `cypress.json` or `cypress.env.json` automatically, so no additional setup would be required. Note: Environment variables stored in `cypress.env.json` will override any set in `cypress.json`.

Either way, after defining the variables at a higher scope than the `it()` block, you can set them in the `before()` or `beforeEach()` of your block.

```js
// assumes value is set in cypress.json
describe('some tests', () => {
  let foo: string;
  
  before(() => {
    foo = Cypress.env('foo');
  });

  it('logs foo value', () => {
    cy.log(foo); // logs 'bar'
  }); 
});
```

EDIT: After discussion, it seems like the actual question being asked is how the data can be set and easily used. I think the easiest way would just be to set the data in the `beforeEach()`.

```js
describe('some test', () => {
  let foo: string;
  beforeEach(() => {
    foo = Cypress.env('foo');
  })

  it('logs bar', { env: { foo: 'bar' } }, () => {
    cy.log(foo); // logs 'bar'
  });

  it('logs baz', { env: { foo: 'baz' } }, () => {
    cy.log(foo); // logs 'baz'
  });
});
```

It may also be valuable to set a default value, in case you have a use case that you're using > 50% of the time.

```js
...
let foo: string;
beforeEach(() => {
  foo = Cypress.env('foo') ?? 'defaultValue'
});
...
```

Comment: So the values are not same for each test, thats why was avoiding the cypress.json and also the env variables since its different set for each test case. Is fixtures an option to use??

Comment: Ah! Ok. I misunderstood your question. If you still want to declare the environment variables in the `it()` block, then you can use `beforeEach()`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of users and index it

```js
// cypress.json
{
  "env": {
    "users": [
      {firstname: 'Lambda', lastname: 'Jonas', email: 'ljrfnew@gemini.com'},
      ...
    ]
  }
}

// test
it('tests with first user', () => {
  const firstname = Cypress.env('users')[0].firstname
  const lastname =  Cypress.env('users')[0].lastname
  ...
})
```

Comment: Good to know about this, i will definitely try it or keep it as a option